# Checkstyle EmptyLineSeparator ignores custom tokens

Tags: java, checkstyle

I would like to have `EmptyLineSeparator` without token `STATIC_INIT` (I am using version 8.36.2).

My simple java-class:

```java
package com.test;

public class Test {
    private static final int[] FIELD = new int[5];
    static {
        FIELD[0] = 16;
        FIELD[1] = 8;
        FIELD[2] = 6;
        FIELD[3] = 10;
        FIELD[4] = 10;
    }
}
```

My checkstyle.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
            <property name="tokens"
            value="PACKAGE_DEF, IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, INSTANCE_INIT,
            METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF, RECORD_DEF, COMPACT_CTOR_DEF"/>
            <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLines" value="false"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

But still seeing that my build is failed, because of :

```sh
/var/tmp $ java -jar checkstyle-8.36.2-all.jar -c config.xml Test.java
Starting audit...
[ERROR] /dev/tmp/Test.java:5:5:
   'STATIC_INIT' should be separated from previous statement. [EmptyLineSeparator]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 1 errors.
```

Have I missed something?
I am expecting no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you excluded STATIC_INIT from tokens list, but you have VARIABLE_DEF in it.
Your violation is reported during field inspection because field definition is not separated. Please note that `allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields` flag is not applicable here since it only for no lines **between** fields, but here you have field and static init block.

When you exclude STATIC_INIT token from check, it means that checkstyle will not check is there something right after this token, e.g. such code will cause no violations

```
public class Test {
    private static final int[] FIELD = new int[5];

    static {
        FIELD[0] = 16;
        FIELD[1] = 8;
        FIELD[2] = 6;
        FIELD[3] = 10;
        FIELD[4] = 10;
    }
    private int myOtherField; // no violation
}
```